# onClick and onBlur issue in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, onblur

I have a text field followed by a button.

The text field has an `onBlur` function and a `onClick` function is accociated with the button.

**Issue**: If I enter some text and click on the button, `onBlur` event triggers but the `onClick` event never gets triggered.

How can I solve this issue?

I'm happy to share the code if required.

Edit: (Adding the code)

```
// This simple onClick is associated with the button.

onClick={(e) => {
    console.log("ONclicked!");
}}>
```

```
// blurHandler associated with the input field

blurHandler = event => {
    if (undefined !== event) event.stopPropagation();
    
    // modifying some states using setState
    
    };
```

**Imp**: the onClick button is not not firing on first click, second click behaves as expected (simple debug message doesn't appear until second click)

Comment: Yes, please share the code if that is not a problem.

Comment: Both events should trigger. We need to see the code to troubleshoot why.

Comment: @sabbir.alam code added.

Comment: @cssyphus I have added some code

Comment: This issues of second is because of lifecycle of react

Comment: On first click , the content inside onclick function doesn't renders